# C# - update Crystal Report in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I try to solve problem, but I am still without success.

I work on Win 8.1, VS2013 community.

I have simple Winform application with DatagridView and Button. Datagridview has one column and is filled with sample values in constructor of form.

```
        private List<StringValue> list;
    private List<Report> lr;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list = new List<StringValue>();
        lr = new List<Report>(); 
        list.Add(new StringValue("bla1"));
        list.Add(new StringValue("bla2"));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
    }
```

As a part of the project I have also dataset component, which is filled after button click. and for each row of datagridview is created crystal report and its name and added to the list.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 1;
        ReportDocument cr;
        try
        {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

            cr = new CrystalReport1();
            dataSet11.DataTable1.Rows.Clear();
            cr.SetDataSource(dataSet11);
            DataRow nr = dataSet11.DataTable1.NewRow();
            nr["sloup1"] = row.Cells["sloup1"].Value;
            dataSet11.DataTable1.Rows.Add(nr);
            cr = new CrystalReport1();
            cr.SetDataSource(dataSet11);
            cr.Refresh();
            lr.Add(new Report(i.ToString(), cr));
            i++;
        }

            ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer(lr);
            viewer.Show();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
}
```

Report class is

```
public class Report
{
    private  string m_name = null;
    private CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument m_document;
    public string Name 
    { 
        get{return m_name;}
        set{m_name = value;}
    }
    public ReportDocument reportDocument 
    {
        get { return m_document; }
        set { m_document = value; }
    }

    public Report(string name, ReportDocument doc)
    {
        m_name = name;
        m_document = doc;
    }
}
```

I created also other form with listBox, where are displayed names of reports and crystalreportviewer control. After click on the item in listbox, I want to open crystalreport sent from form1. Here is source code:

```
List<Report> lr = null;
    public ReportViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ReportViewer(List<Report> reports) : this()
    {
        lr = reports;
        foreach (Report report in reports)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(report.Name);
        }
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        crView.ReportSource = null;
        ReportDocument rep = new ReportDocument();
        rep = GetReport(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
        crView.ReportSource = rep;
        this.crView.RefreshReport();

    }

    private ReportDocument GetReport(int p)
    {
        return lr[p].reportDocument;
    }
}
```

and now what is problem: when I click on the item in listbox, in viewer is displayed only last report. There are two items with different name, but onlz one report.
If i tried show reports for each created report at form1, values and reports were OK, but in the selectedindexchanged event both reportdocument are the same.
Where is error please?
How to update crzstal report, so it will display correct data?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmmm. I recommend you try debugging. Nice try, stackoverflow is not jira.

Comment: Thanks, I tried debugging of course.

Comment: Sorry, that was flippant. What I mean to say is asking the "there's a bug in my code" sort of question isn't the best way to get help on this site. It's much better to [break it down](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) into something we can help you with. [More asking advice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).